# Does $0$ as an element belongs to the vector space $C[a,b]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

Does $0$ as an element belongs to the vector space $C[a,b]$?

I am thinking that if $C[a,b]$ is the set of all functions with domain $[a,b]$ and it has been established that $C$ is a vector space, then it complies with the closure property $\forall f,g \in C[a,b](f+g \in C[a,b])$. At the same time within the set of all functions is contained the *additive inverse* of each one of them, so $\forall f \in C[a,b](\exists g \in C[0,1](f + g = 0))$... therefore $0$ has to be able to be regarded as a function?

Comment: Zero is an element of a vector space by definition. So, you can not call $C[a,b]$ vectors space if $0$ is not in it.

Comment: To differentiate the two, we usually write that as the $\textbf  ZERO   FUNCTION$ but not 0 in order to not mix up with the zero in the usual sense.
And the zero function should be regarded as a constant function always having zero as its value rather than a ordinary number.

Comment: @Boby, after seeing Omnomnomnom's answer, I noticed that my question was more trivial than I thought, yes, you are right, 0 is the element that fulfills the axiom that states that $\exists \overrightarrow{0}\in V(\overrightarrow{x}+\overrightarrow{0}=\overrightarrow{x})$ in order for $V$ to be a vector space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the function $f:[a,b] \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x) = 0$ is the additive identity of $C[a,b]$.